# Super conductivity of black holes

Tags: black-hole

We all know that we cannot see black holes due to its strong gravitational force. But I think gravity is not the cause for invisibility of black holes. The temperature of a black hole is  1.4×10<sup>-14</sup>. At these low temperature any body can act as super conductor due to Meissner effect. So that's why we are not seeing black holes due to this effect. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Superconductors are not, in general, invisible (google images search for superconductor returns many results). Also, a black hole is more or less defined as a region of space from which light cannot escape due to gravity.

Comment: Sir thank you for answering my question. But  I am saying it might be one of the reason why we cannot see black holes. And if gravity is the cause the larger stars should glow dim when compared to other stars why they are glowing brighter as they are also having strong gravity.

Comment: Tony, as Steve pointed out, it actually could not be one of the reasons, as the very terminology used to describe black holes means it is specifically gravity which is the cause.

Comment: @TonyStark the light from large stars is actually slightly reduced by their gravity -- look up "gravitational redshift" but this is made up for by the fact that they are hotter and have a larger surface to radiate from. Black holes are **much** more compact than stars of the same mass, so the effect is much more dramatic.

Comment: Sir, u are saying it is not the reason why we cannot see black holes